# jquery fadeIn does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, fadein

This does not seem to do anything. what am I doing wrong.

here is my script src:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#block-image').hide().fadeIn(slow);
    });
</script>
```

block-image :

```
<div id="block-image"></div>
```

the script and div tags have <> around them, I'm just unable to write them here without them disappearing.

css file sets style of this div, I have tried Display: none; in the css still nothing.

I have crossed checked my script against countless sources, and I just can't see whats wrong, I am sure my html is fine no hidden " or spelling errors.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `.fadeIn("slow")`. With "".

Otherwise it's looking for a variable named 'slow'.

And your script is included incorrectly (check other answers, I don't want to copy them :)).

Comment: You're faster than me :P but there's a Fiddle I made that reflects your answer http://jsfiddle.net/teJQg/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put code in script tag with src attribute setted, use it like this: 
{code is just ignored}

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#block-image').hide().fadeIn(slow);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#block-image').hide().fadeIn("slow");
   });
</script>
```